# How to replace access specifiers with its data in a strings?

Tags: c++, c

HI I have following three strings,

```
char* string1, string2, string3;
printf("First string = %s", string1);
printf("Second string = %s", string2);
printf("Third string = %s", string3);
```

Output of above code is,

```
First string = My Content is : %s, My value is : %d
Second string = Open source OS
Thirf string = 100
```

Now i need to merge the string2 and string3 content at the place of %s & %d simultaneousaly, so that i should get following string,

```
My Content is :  Open source OS
My value is :  100
```

can any one suggest me how to add the above two strings to another string. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify string1,string2 and string3 are in the code more elaborately ?

Comment: Nobody noticed. But you only have one string `string1` and two char variables. `string2` and `string3` are actually only chars. Thus the second third printf() statements are invalid. Thus why they are working is a complete mystery or you have made a cut paste mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprintf` along with `printf` as:

```
char format[1024]; 
sprintf(format, "First string = %s", string1); //this makes the format string
printf(format, value1, value2); //this prints output with the formatted string
```

Comment: Thanks Nawaz, can u tell me what is type of format? i tried by taking char *, but it didn't give expected results.

Comment: @BSalunke: `format` is declared as `char format[1024]`. Noticed that?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
printf(string1, string2, atoi(string3));
```

Comment: Hi Eran, NO, Its not working. do u have any another solution.